# Changing font for numbers in entire document

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums

Salam,

I would like to ask an advice whether its possible to change font for numbers in the document.
In essence, I have prepared a manuscript of a book (some **200** pages).
I am using `OldStandard` font, because I like it's "antique" look. 
However, I do not like how the numbers are displayed. I would like to have something more "old-fashioned",
for example packge `Latin Modern Roman` has nice Oldstyle numbers. Is there a way to have OldStandard for text and Oldstyle numbers 
from Latin Modern Roman? 
I am using MikTex, TexStudio as my editor, compiling with LuaLaTeX.
Here is a "minimal" piece of code:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{OldStandard}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\usepackage{microtype} % better management of overfulls
\setmainlanguage{english} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]  
{\large 0123456789}
\textbf{{\large 0123456789}}
\textit{{\large 0123456789}}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I would strongly advise against combining fonts in that manner. Instead use a font that supports lowercase numbers. Since OldStandard is listed the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffontscategorised.html) you could just find another so called "Didone Font" that matches your requirements.